# Running Total Using LAG Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wonder if someone could help me calculate a running total.

I am converting this from an existing excel solution so i know what i am aiming for.

I am trying to use LAG to get the values from the previous row but the calculation is not matching my target. I think i need to use the result from the previous row in the lag column but that doesn't look possible.

Any help appreciated.

```
use tempdb;

--Create Temp Table 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#WareHouseData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #WareHouseData
CREATE TABLE #WareHouseData
   ( 
      ItemId    INT,
      DateID    INT,
      OpenningWareHouseUnits INT,
      FcastSales INT,
      GoodsIncoming INT,
      TargetRunningStock INT
   ); 

--Fill It With example Data
--OpenningWareHouseUnits only exists in the first week 
--Fcast sales can be in any week though normally all weeks
--Goods Incoming can be in any weeks
INSERT INTO #WareHouseData  
    ([ItemId],[DateID],[OpenningWareHouseUnits],[FcastSales],[GoodsIncoming],[TargetRunningStock])
VALUES  
(987654,201450,200,10,NULL,190),
(987654,201451,NULL,20,NULL,170),
(987654,201452,NULL,30,NULL,140),
(987654,201501,NULL,20,NULL,120),
(987654,201502,NULL,10,NULL,110),
(987654,201503,NULL,50,NULL,60),
(987654,201504,NULL,60,NULL,0),
(987654,201505,NULL,70,100,30),
(987654,201506,NULL,70,80,40),
(987654,201507,NULL,80,100,60),
(987654,201508,NULL,30,NULL,30),
(987654,201509,NULL,20,NULL,10),
(987654,201510,NULL,20,NULL,0),
(123456,201450,300,50,NULL,250),
(123456,201451,NULL,60,NULL,190),
(123456,201452,NULL,70,100,220),
(123456,201501,NULL,80,NULL,140),
(123456,201502,NULL,100,100,140),
(123456,201503,NULL,105,NULL,35),
(123456,201504,NULL,100,100,35),
(123456,201505,NULL,95,NULL,0),
(123456,201506,NULL,30,100,70),
(123456,201507,NULL,20,NULL,50),
(123456,201508,NULL,5,NULL,45),
(123456,201509,NULL,5,NULL,40),
(123456,201510,NULL,5,NULL,35),
(369258,201450,1000,100,NULL,900),
(369258,201451,NULL,100,NULL,800),
(369258,201452,NULL,100,NULL,700),
(369258,201501,NULL,100,NULL,600),
(369258,201502,NULL,100,NULL,500),
(369258,201503,NULL,100,NULL,400),
(369258,201504,NULL,100,NULL,300),
(369258,201505,NULL,100,NULL,200),
(369258,201506,NULL,100,NULL,100),
(369258,201507,NULL,100,500,500),
(369258,201508,NULL,100,NULL,400),
(369258,201509,NULL,100,NULL,300),
(369258,201510,NULL,100,NULL,200);
;


--Match The Target Runing Stock Total
--I need to match the TargetRunningStock Totals
--This can be recreated in excel by pasting the columns 
--{ItemId   DateID  OpenningWareHouseUnits  FcastSales  GoodsIncoming}
--Into cell A1 with headers, and pasting this formula 
-- =IF(C2="",IF((F1-D2+E2)<0,0,(F1-D2+E2)),(C2-D2+E2)) into cell F2  
SELECT w.ItemId
    ,   w.DateID    
    ,   w.OpenningWareHouseUnits    
    ,   w.FcastSales    
    ,   w.GoodsIncoming 
    ,   w.TargetRunningStock
    ,   CASE WHEN w.OpenningWareHouseUnits IS NOT NULL
             THEN (ISNULL(w.OpenningWareHouseUnits,0) - ISNULL(w.FcastSales,0) + ISNULL(w.GoodsIncoming,0))
             ELSE  CASE WHEN ((((LAG(ISNULL(w.OpenningWareHouseUnits,0),1)  OVER (PARTITION BY w.ItemId  ORDER BY w.ItemId,w.DateID))- 
                                    (LAG(ISNULL(w.FcastSales,0),1)  OVER (PARTITION BY w.ItemId  ORDER BY w.ItemId,w.DateID)) + 
                                        (LAG(ISNULL(w.GoodsIncoming,0),1)  OVER (PARTITION BY w.ItemId  ORDER BY w.ItemId,w.DateID)))) -
                                ISNULL(w.FcastSales,0) + ISNULL(w.GoodsIncoming,0)) < 0
                        THEN 0
                        ELSE ((((LAG(ISNULL(w.OpenningWareHouseUnits,0),1)  OVER (PARTITION BY w.ItemId  ORDER BY w.ItemId,w.DateID))- 
                                    (LAG(ISNULL(w.FcastSales,0),1)  OVER (PARTITION BY w.ItemId  ORDER BY w.ItemId,w.DateID)) + 
                                        (LAG(ISNULL(w.GoodsIncoming,0),1)  OVER (PARTITION BY w.ItemId  ORDER BY w.ItemId,w.DateID)))) -
                                ISNULL(w.FcastSales,0) + ISNULL(w.GoodsIncoming,0))
                     END
            END  CalculatedRunningStock
FROM #WareHouseData w
ORDER BY w.ItemId
    ,   w.DateID
```

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring most of the calculation logic for simplicity (and time), you almost certainly need to `sum() over (partition by ... order by...)`.

```
select ItemId, DateId, TargetRunningStock, 
       sum(TargetRunningStock) over (partition by itemid order by dateid)
from WarehouseData
order by ItemId, DateId;
```

```
ItemId  DateId  TargetRunningStock  Sum
--
123456  201450  250                 250
123456  201451  190                 440
123456  201452  220                 660
...
987654  201507  60                  920
987654  201508  30                  950
987654  201509  10                  960
987654  201510   0                  960
```

Since you're trying to reproduce the results from a spreadsheet, you might need to wrap something like this around some calculated columns that use lag(). I didn't look that deeply into your spreadsheet logic.

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax for a running sum is to use an `order by` in the `partition` clause for the `sum()` window function:

```
SELECT w.ItemId, w.DateID, w.OpenningWareHouseUnits, w.FcastSales,
       w.GoodsIncoming, w.TargetRunningStock,
       SUM(OpenningWareHouseUnits) OVER (PARTITION BY w.ItemId, w.DateId)
FROM #WareHouseData w
ORDER BY w.ItemId, w.DateID ;
```

I am a little unclear how to apply this to your formula.  Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
SELECT ItemID
   , DateID
   , TargetRunningStock
   , SUM(COALESCE(OpenningWareHouseUnits, 0) + COALESCE(GoodsIncoming, 0) - COALESCE(FcastSales,0)) OVER(Partition by ItemID ORDER BY DateID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS CalcTarg
FROM WareHouseData
ORDER BY ItemID, DateID;
```

I tested it and it seems to match your TargetRunningStock pretty well except that I allowed it to run into the negatives instead of just going to 0 for restocking purposes.